# How to scrape https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/ with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this page because it was in the tutorial I followed here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UG2x2iWerk&t=36s

However, it's not working for me. First, I got a 403 forbidden error. So I disguised as mozilla/chrome. Then I was able to get a response but it appears to be a raw javascript bundle, not a rendered html page. Am I missing something here?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# crawl IMDB Top 250 and randomly select a movie
URL = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
#response = requests.get(URL,  headers={"User-Agent": "Chrome"})
response = requests.get(URL,  headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Also when I redirect the output to a file and open it as html with a browser locally, I get a perfectly rendered movie list exactly as on the website.

Comment: If you do "view source" in your browser for https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/, you'll see that it's indeed mostly JS. That's what the server sends you. Your browser then runs that JS, and _that_ generates the HTML.

Comment: I understand that that's what the server sends. Are you saying BeautifulSoup won't execute any javascript? All it can do is take the raw response from the server? Btw. I'm new to BeautifulSoup so I'm not exactly sure what to expect.

Comment: @Ya. Yes, for these sorts of scenarios you should look into either the API or web automation software like Selenium.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser. It parses HTML. That's all it does. It's not a Web browser.

Comment: IMDB has [an API](https://developer.imdb.com/) you can use to get data in a machine readable format, but you'll probably have to pay for it.

Comment: Well API would be best approache, but all inforamtion is in your response, so may take a closer look to: [How to scrape individual text from one tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569917/how-to-scrape-individual-text-from-one-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the comments say that it's JS. Ok, but that doesn't mean you can't get the URLs inside this page, the JS in this page would just change how the elements are rendered, not create new elements (that's in your case).

My solution here is to save the output you get from requests to an html file, and then inspecting it, or trying to find the tag that you want without class names (for example, all `a` tags)

Another solution which would work if the JS is supposed to also get the page content by making requests to some API, is by disabling internet and opening that HTML file in your browser to see which elements are there and not loaded from other requests.

Hers's an updated code that will do the job:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random


# crawl IMDB Top 250 and randomly select a movie
URL = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
#response = requests.get(URL,  headers={"User-Agent": "Chrome"})
response = requests.get(URL,  headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

with open("hi.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = [i for i in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"ipc-title-link-wrapper"}) if '/title/' in i['href']]
selected_movie = random.choice(links)
print('http://www.imdb.com' + selected_movie['href'])
print(selected_movie.text)
```

This will pick all the `a` tags that have the class name as `ipc-title-link-wrapper`, and will only pick the ones that have `/title/` in the link.

I hope this helped and I recommend learning Selenium after you master beautifulsoup.